# C++ Templates - How to use across multiple MTU's

Tags: c++, design-patterns, templates, boost, shared-ptr

```
class A : boost::noncopyable {
    int type;

    A(int type, enum e) : type(type) { /* ... */ }
}
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr;


template <enum VAR>
class B : boost::noncopyable {
    static A_ptr x, y;

    B() {
        if (!x.get()) {
            x.reset(new A(0, VAR));
        }
        if (!y.get()) {
            y.reset(new A(1, VAR));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have several types of 'B' based on the template ; that way it will keep separate statics and 'tracking' of their own `x`, `y` (A_ptrs).

**The Question(s):**

a) How do I set this up into a header/source configuration, with the templates working correctly?

b) Should I form a 'createA' function instead of the `x.reset(new A(0, VAR));`

c) Is the shared_ptr.get() guaranteed to return 0 (ie false in a boolean expression) when uninitialized?

Should I split b) and c) across multiple SO questions?

Comment: N.B. a `shared_ptr` cannot be "uninitialized", it will be default-constructed if you do not provide an initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Set it up like this:

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_HEADER_GUARD
#define A_HEADER_GUARD

class A {...};

#endif
```

A.cpp:

```
// A::method1 implementation
// A::method2 implementation
// etc...
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_HEADER_GUARD
#define B_HEADER_GUARD

#include "A.h"

template <enum VAR> class B {...}

#endif
```

Note that class B can't be implemented in a cpp file. This is because class B is a template and its implementation must completely visible to whoever instantiates the template.

Make sure you understand the use of [header guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) (aka include guards).

---

b) Writing private helper methods to "factor out" frequently repeated code is quite normal, and I'd say even encouraged.

---

c) Yes, `shared_ptr::get()` is guaranteed to be 0 when uninitialised, as stated in the *postconditions* clauses in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Instead of checking `shared_ptr::get()` in a condition expression, you can just check the `shared_ptr` itself. It automatically converts itself to `bool` when used in a boolean context. For example:

```
shared_ptr<A> a_ptr;
if (!a_ptr)
    cout << "a_ptr not initialized!";
```

This is the idiomatic way of checking smart pointer validity.